# Remember data in previous session of the web page

Tags: javascript, html, onload

I have a javascript enabled html page where a there are 3 text fields. When I reload the page, I would like the text fields retain the values I had earlier filled. Is this possible?

I have tried this way.

`function Load() {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("name");
}
function Unload() {
    localStorage.setItem("name", document.getElementById("text").innerHTML);
}`

Comment: Please add enough code to create a [mre]. What's not working? Where are you stuck?